# Doctrine: insert related object (tag) if not exists in db

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine

I'm creating a simple blog post systems. I just have 2 entities News and Tag.

I created a "manyToMany" relation between News and Tag.

Doctrine created a third table (called news_tag) in my database to map the relation between my news and my tag like this one:

```
+------+----------+------+
|  ID  |  news_id |tag_id|  
+------+----------+------+
|  1   |  1       |  1   | 
|  2   |  1       |  2   | 
|  3   |  2       |  3   | 
|  4   |  2       |  2   | 
+------+----------+------+
```

The relation works fine when I add a news in my db. The tag are mapped to the news automatically

My problem is:
The field 'name' of my tag table is unique. Which is normal I think.

Ok let's say I'm adding 2 news both having the same tag 'november' . . . I will get a violation of unique key constraint !

I thought Dotrine was able to understand in this case it should not try to insert a duplicated tag in my tag table.

I would like in this case doctrine would map only the relation of the duplicated tag (by inserting relation in my table called news_tag) without inserting the tag into the table called 'tag' (which will obviously throw a violation of unique key constraint)

Can you help me to solve that problem ?

Edit here is the code of my controller to add a news:

```
   public function insertNewsAction(Request $request)
    {
        try{
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $news = new News();

        $formNews = $this->createForm(NewsType::class, $news);
        $formNews->handleRequest($request);
        $postedDatas = $formNews->getData();

        /* handling of tags field  */      
        $tagsTemp = $postedDatas->getTags();
        $tags = explode(';', $tagsTemp);

        // convert textfield  of my form to ArrayCollection 
        $news->setTags(new ArrayCollection);

        foreach($tags as $singleTag)
        {
            $tag = new Tag();
            $tag->setName($singleTag);
            $news->addTag($tag);
        }

        $em->persist($news);
        $em->flush();
        $this->addFlash('notice', 'News is correctly inserted');

        return $this->render('MyBundle:Form:news.html.twig');
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            $this->addFlash('error', 'Flush error. Error news1');
            $this->render('MyBundle:Form:news.html.twig');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please, show us your code. I guess you're creating new `Tag` entities for every `post`, while you should reuse them...

Comment: Yes it's right I'm creating new Tag entity for each post. I'm posting my code in 2minute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that you are creating new `Tag` entities for every post, so `Doctrine` tries to persist them and then the database complaints about your unique restriction.

Your insert code should look similar to:

```
$news = //get the NEWS to persist
foreach($tags as $tag)
{
    if (($persistedTag = $entityManager->getRepository('AppBundle:Tag')->findOneByName($tag))==null)
    {
        $persistedTag = new Tag();
        //Fill the new Tag entity
        $entityManager->persist($persistedTag);
    }
    $persistedTag->addNews($news);
    $news->addTag($persistedTag);
}
$entityManager->flush();
```

Comment: Yes I have already tried to implement that solution and it works fine. 

But should I update myself the table called 'news_tag' to map the relation ? 

Simple example: I already have the tag with name 'november' in my databse . . . 
Ok now I'm inserting a new News which has tag 'november' . . .  I don't insert the tag ok but I need to map that news to the tag 'novemeber' . . . Can I update the table called news_tag ?

Comment: Look at my proposed code: You need to find the 'november'  tag and add it to the news. Also, add the news to that tag (in my code I call it `$persistedTag`)

Comment: Sorry but in my Tag entity I do not have a property called 'news'. Is this a bi-directional relation ?

I'm trying to implement your solution I come back in 10 minutes

Comment: Ok, I always configure it as bidirectional relationships... Try it and let me know

Comment: THANK YOU :-) it works fine. So this are the steps I followed to solve that problem:

1. configuring the relation of news and tags to be manyToMany  "bi-directional".

2. when configuring I set this line in Tag.orm.yml (I use YML) cascade: ["persist", "merge"] . . . 

3. Don't forget to update with doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle:Tag

4. Implementing the code of Oscar Pérez. in NewsController

That's all. Thank you and and Have a good day @Oscar Pérez :-)

Comment: Edit: The Oscar Pérez solution is the good one. I just edit this post to tell I needed to add this line of code to avoid my Tag object has no name when I add news tag in my table: $persistedTag->setName($tag);

I added this line just before the line: $entityManager->persist($persistedTag);

Comment: @zm455 : Glad to have helped!